# How to .append values to a textbox using <a onclick and then also delete last value added (values = 0-9)

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-3, append

As the title says I'm trying to basically added the numbers 0-9 to a text box and also be able to delete the last input number(basically last digit in textbox or decrease length of data by 1 or w/e to produce this).

Like you can see below I've setup basically a keypad of buttons which I'm trying to record the value of each to a specific textbox.

```
<%: Html.TextBox("TBBlah") %>

<a onclick="$('#TBBlah').append('7');" class="large button" style="color:Black; text-decoration:none;">7</a>
    &nbsp;
    <a onclick="$('#TBBlah').append('8');" class="large button" style="color:Black; text-decoration:none;">8</a>
    &nbsp;
    <a onclick="$('#TBBlah').append('9');" class="large button" style="color:Black; text-decoration:none;">9</a>
```

I'm trying to set this up in this precise way to allow users to enter a code via a touchscreen.

With the code above it says Object doesn't support this property or method which has me wondering what I did wrong.

also was wondering in case this would help (these are in my site.master file)

```
<!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="<%= Url.Content("~/scripts/jquery-1.6.2.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="<%= Url.Content("~/scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- /jQuery--> 

    <!-- jQuery UI -->
    <script src="<%= Url.Content("~/content/script/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="<%= Url.Content("~/content/css/cupertino/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css") %>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <!-- /jQuery UI -->
```

I hope I haven't missed out anything but if I have ask and I shall provide.

Comment: Quick point, you don't need the two jQuery scripts. You only need one. The one without the min is uncompressed code or development code, and the one with the min is compressed code for production.

Comment: removed the min version for now but any idea how I would go about deleting a number in the same way I would add 1? (by this I just mean it would be in an onclick event hopefully)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`append` can't be used in your case since it will append something to the text inside some element, whereas in your case you are adding text into `textbox` which should use `text` property to access its content.

**CORRECTED VERSION:**

```
onclick= "$('#TBBlah').val($('#TBBlah').val() + $(this).text())" ;
```

This will append the newly clicked number to the value inside `textbox`.

Comment: I don't quite see how that works. Since on the face of it your getting the `text` of the `#TBBlah` and adding it to the `text` of `this`, which won't change the result of `#TBBlah` since strings are immutable.

Comment: And `text` works in the same way as `append`. It puts text between the tags, or gets the text between the tags.

Comment: Yeh I just finished trying the invalid code and a number of different ways to use this code and nothing would work.

For starters it doesn't seem to indicate where you would assign the value for the text to be input to the textbox so I tried to put it into $(this).text(); for example '9' and 9.  Since I have now noticed u put up I corrected version I'll try seeing if I can get that to work and look at nebulafox's solution.

Comment: Ok so all I had to do was replace $(this).text(); with the value itself so '9', now I just need to figure out how to delete and why <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#TBBlah").mask("9999999999");
    });

</script> is causing problems

Comment: You could delete the last number using following:
str= $('#TBBlah').val();
$('#TBBlah').val(str.substring(0, str.length - 1) );

Answer (score 0):

It help to find out what `HTML.TextBox` actually created was an input field. You don't want to `append`, wich adds stuff between two tags you want to add the to the input value. So

```
onclick="$('#TBBlah').val( '7' );"
```

Here's a link for you: http://api.jquery.com/val

And for the way Ghazanfar Mir did it

```
onclick="$('#TBBlah').val( $(this).text() );"
```